# run every TestCase inside a module

Tags: django, django-testing

How can you run tests from all `TestCase` classes, in a specific module under tests package?

In a Django project, I have split tests.py under tests/ 
Each file(module) has several TestCase classes, and each of them having several test methods.
**init**.py imports each of them.

I already know that I can do these:

1. Run all the test:

   ```
   ./manage.py test myapp
   ```
2. Or run specific TestCase:

   ```
   ./manage.py test myapp.OneOfManyTestCase
   ```
3. Or run very specific test method from a TestCase class:

   ```
   ./manage.py test myapp.OneOfManyTestCase.test_some_small_method
   ```

However, I can't figure out how to run every TestCases from a particular module. 
Say, `OneOfManyTestCase` class is from `tests/lot_of_test.py`, and there are other test cases too. 
Django doesn't seem to care about modules with TestCases.

How can I run all the TestCases inside `lot_of_test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up [writing down my own TestSuiteRunner](https://gist.github.com/jangxyz/4962222), like [@sneawo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1885757/sneawo) said.

After Django-style fails, try importing as usual python-style.

[One line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.3/django/test/simple.py#L261) to fix:

```py
suite.addTest(build_test(label))
```

into

```
try:
    suite.addTest(django.test.simple.build_test(label))
except ValueError:
    # change to python-style package name
    head, tail = label.split('.', 1)
    full_label = '.'.join([head, django.test.simple.TEST_MODULE, tail])
    # load tests
    tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(full_label)
    suite.addTests(tests)
```

and set `TEST_RUNNER` in `settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER='myapp.tests.module_test_suite_runner.ModuleTestSuiteRunner'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to achieve this you need to subclass your own TestRunner from [DjangoTestSuiteRunner](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/simple.py#L238) and override `build_suite` method.

Comment: Ended up doing this. Thanks for the tip :)